# How do I set the directory-abbrev-alist values?

Tags: abbrev

I'd like to customize this value - it's briefly mentioned in the manual.

How can this be done?

Comment: The question is unclear (to me). Are you asking how to use Customize? Are you asking how to use Customize in the context of only this option - e.g., having a problem defining its value? Are you asking about what the option is about and looking for an explanation of its possible values? Just what have you tried and what was missing or unclear?

Comment: Like all other variables, you can customize iv with `M-x customize-variable` or by adding `(setq directory-abbrev-alist ...)` to your `~/,emacs` file.  So I suggest you give a bit more details about what it is you'd like to do, so we can provide more useful answers.

Answer (score 2):

I also needed this in order to change the `directory-abbrev-list` so that the function [`abbreviate-file-name`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Directory-Names.html) would shorten paths that are not children of my 'home' path.

Managed to do it with the following command, to create an abbreviation from "c:/This/Is/My/path" to "path":

- `` (setq directory-abbrev-alist (cons '("\\`c:/Abbreviate/This/Path" . "abbreviated") directory-abbrev-alist)) ``
  appends a new abbreviation, and
- `` (setq directory-abbrev-alist '(("\\`c:/Abbreviate/This/Path" . "abbreviated"))) ``
  assigns only one element to the list.